# How to import daily csv data into table with generated columns postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, copy

I'm new to PostgreSQL and and looking for some guidance and best practice.

I have created a table by importing data from a csv file. I then altered the table by creating multiple generated columns like this:

```
ALTER TABLE master
ADD office VARCHAR(50)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CASE WHEN LEFT(location,4)='Chic' THEN 'CHI'
                     ELSE LEFT(location,strpos(location,'_')-1) END) STORED;
```

But when I try to import new data into the table I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "office" is a generated column
DETAIL:  Generated columns cannot be used in COPY.
```

My goal is to be able to import new data each day to the table and have the generated columns automatically populate in order to transform the data as I would like. How can I do so?

Comment: Does your importable data (the csv file) contain "office" column? Which command do you execute when importing new data?

Comment: @Johnny the csv file doesn't contain office, office is a generated column based on the "location" column in csv. I just use import option to import new data which i believe uses copy function. i could use a different function, just not sure how

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE master (location VARCHAR);

ALTER TABLE master
ADD office VARCHAR
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CASE
        WHEN LEFT(location, 4) = 'Chic' THEN 'CHI'
        ELSE LEFT(location, strpos(location, '_') - 1)
    END
) STORED;
                     
--INSERT INTO master (location) VALUES ('Chicago');
--INSERT INTO master (location) VALUES ('New_York');

COPY master (location) FROM $$d:\cities.csv$$ CSV;

SELECT * FROM master;
```

Is this the structure and the behaviour you are expecting? If not, please provide more details regarding your table structure, your importable data and your importing commands.

Also, maybe when you try to import the csv file, the columns are not linked properly, or maybe the delimiter is not properly set. Try to specify each column in the exact order that appear in your csv file.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html

**Note:** `d:\cities.csv` contains:

```
Chicago
New_York
```

**EDIT:**

If columns positions are mixed up between table and csv, the following operation may come in handy:

```
1. create temporary table tmp (csv_column1 <data_type>, csv_column_2 <data_type>, ...); (including ALL csv columns)
2. copy tmp from '/path/to/file.csv';
3. insert into master (location, other_info, ...) select csv_column_3 as location, csv_column_7 as other_info, ... from tmp;
```

Importing data using an intermediate table may slow things down a little, but gives you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Thanks!  I think this is close, but I have many columns in this csv, location is just one of them. There are also additional generated columns. So would I have to call out each column specifically? I get the following error after trying above:  ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY attend, line 1: "col1,col2,col3"

Comment: That error may occur because not all of csv columns were specified in COPY command or the csv column count is not consistent through all the rows. If column positions are mixed up (comparing the table and csv file), then I recommend to perform this operation in three clear steps, using temporary tables (I've edited the answer with details). Also, for debugging, I would recommend to test the csv with only a few lines (1-2) carefully checked, because maybe the csv contains rows unexpectedly wrong-formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when importing to PG from a csv - I found that even though my column was generated, I still had to have it in the imported data, just left it empty. Worked fine when the column name was in there and mapped to my DB col name.